# wanted to create flag for salary in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, if-statement

I would like to set a `flag` column to `if salary > 200 then flag='high' else 'low'`.

`test1` is my DataFrame.

dataframe:

```
policyID  salary           line

119736      100       Residential                     

206893      1000    Commercial

172534      70      Residential

785275       500     Residential
```

I'm using this code:

```
for i in test1['salary']:
    if i > 200:
       test1['flag']='high'
    elif i < 200:
       test1['flag']='low'

print (test1)
```

it's giving me flag = high only.

Comment: Can you post your df?

Comment: policyID          county  SITE_limit  salary         line  \
0    119736     CLAY COUNTY         200     100  Residential   
1    448094     CLAY COUNTY         400     200  Residential   
2    206893     CLAY COUNTY        2000    1000   Commercial   
3    333743     CLAY COUNTY        1000     500  Residential

Comment: or you can create just random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best here is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
test1['flag'] = np.where(test1['salary'] > 200, 'high', 'low')
```

Not recommended loop solution because slow:

```
L = []
for i in test1['salary']:
    if i > 200:
       L.append('high')
    else:
       L.append('low')

df["flag"] = L
```

Or:

```
for i, row in test1.iterrows():
    if row['salary'] > 200:
       test1.loc[i, 'flag']='high'
    else:
       test1.loc[i, 'flag']='low'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but can I do it using if and else statements.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
df["flag"] = df["salary"].apply(lambda x: 'high' if x > 200 else 'low')
```